# Ubuntu 18.04 with VS Code - top of each row of characters in terminal is cut off

Tags: 18.04, display, ide

This is what my terminal in VS Code looks like:

[image: VS Code screenshot]

The top of each row of characters is cut off. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04. Anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",` in VS Code Settings

Comment: that did the trick.